# Alternative of singleLine attribute (Deprecated) TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I recently used **`TextInputEditText`** and I got lint error that `singleLine` attribute is **Deprecated**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/my_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/string_hint_dob"
            android:lines="5"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Getting strike-through as below:

[image]

Is there any alternative way for this?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The `android:singleLine` attribute has been deprecated since [API Level 15](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#singleLine). You can achieve the same behaviour by using `android:maxLines`, which allows you to specify an arbitrary number of lines. This is superior to `android:singleLine`, which restricts you to only allowing one line.

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minLines="2"
     android:maxLines="2" /> <!-- can specify arbitrary number of max lines -->
```

Comment: It may be superior, but sadly [causes crashes](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33868).

Comment: Not working while view is inside fragment. please help

Comment: doesn't allow imeoption actionNext when using digits

Comment: This does not seem to work unless you also add  android:inputType="text" -- see @Arihant answer below

Answer (score 53):

Always define input type for single line

ex : `inputType="text"`

You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: Combining `maxLines="1"` and `inputType="text"` you get the same behaviour. Great!!

Comment: sometimes `maxLines="1"` does not work. It is `inputType`  that saved me

Comment: I don't know about others but support widgets(AppCompatEditText and AppCompatTextView) definitely need an inputType for maxLines to work.

Comment: I was already setting  maxLines property but inputType was missing. Your answer was really helpful. Thanks Arihant.

Answer (score 40):

`android:singleLine` is deprecated since API 3, you have to use `android:maxLines` instead (in your case `android:maxLines="1"`).

The reason of the deprecation is for its bad performance. Anyway the `singleLine` attribute will not be removed because it's still the only way to make some effects that `android:maxLines` can't make:

e.g.

This will produce a scrolling horizontal text on one line if the text is selected.

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Instead, this won't work:

```
<TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Comment: Also, android:singleLine="true" allows to check for newline characters and move to next field. android:maxLines="1" does not.

Comment: Exactly I agree with you Fondesa. But is there any alternate for this??

Comment: @MashukKhan I didn't find it, if you find a way to do it, tell me, I'll update my answer for other users.

Comment: `This will produce a scrolling horizontal text on one line if the text is selected` it's not working for me even I did `android:singleLine="true"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"`

Answer (score 21):

```
<EditText
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:inputType="text"
      android:maxLines="1"
      />
```

use `android:inputType="text"` and `android:maxLines="1"` togather

Comment: While only setting maxLines didn't help, setting inputType as well did.

Answer (score 6):

Following a commment of Juan José Melero Gómez, I would like to add more information:

If you are attempting to set an `imeAction` to your `EditText` such as `actionSearch`, setting `android:maxLines="1"` won't be enough. Adding `android:inputType="text"` is **mandatory** if you want to see the search icon.

Answer (score 0):

Needed replace `android:singleLine="true"` to `android:maxLines="1"` if you want indicate `imeOptions`  needed add this line `android:inputType="number|text ..."`