# How to effectively replace singleLine with maxLines in style?

Tags: android, android-styles, android-singleline

I have a style as below

```
<style name="PennyTextSingleLine">
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_penny</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_default</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
</style>
```

And later I have another style that is all the same except not single line. So I write

```
<style name="PennyTextMultiLine" parent="PennyTextSingleLine">
    <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
</style>
```

That's very useful.

However, as we know singleLine is deprecated as per [Alternative of singleLine attribute (Deprecated) TextInputEditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080073/alternative-of-singleline-attribute-deprecated-textinputedittext). It is suppose to be replaced by

```
<item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
```

How could I tackle the above (e.g. any way to represent the below with `maxLines`)?

```
<item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know I can do the below

```
<style name="PennyTextSingleLine" parent="PennyTextMultiLine">
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>

<style name="PennyTextMultiLine" >
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_penny</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_default</item>
</style>
```

But, that would involve too many search around of my existing codes to swap the hierarchical relationship. I wonder if there's a 1-1 where we could override the `maxlines=1` to any number at the parent hierarchy.

Post my answer here, but hope for a better answer out there.