# moving text in textview without using android:singleLine

Tags: java, android

I have next TextView configuration:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:focusable="true"  
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
    android:text="TextViewTextVie1wTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView TextViewTextVie1wTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

and next line in onCreate() method in MainActivity:

```
findViewById(R.id.test).setSelected(true);
```

So, text in textView is moving.
Have can I make the same behavior without using `android:singleLine` because it is deprecated.
current API 19

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative of singleLine attribute (Deprecated) TextInputEditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080073/alternative-of-singleline-attribute-deprecated-textinputedittext)

Comment: add `android:maxLines="1"` to your xml

Comment: I tried to change android:singleLine="true" to android:maxLines="1" but it not helped. text not moving anymore.

Comment: Use both `android:maxLines="1"` and `android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: But `android:singleLine="true"` is deprecated. I want to find alternative way.

Comment: I try to play arround with android:maxLines="1" and android:singleLine="true", but it not work :(